# How to create a default system wide dconf setting starting from just created ad-hoc user config?

Tags: centos, gnome, mate-desktop, dconf, gsettings

I'm in need to standardize (a default standard desktop configuration for all existent and new users) a GNOME environment starting from an existent configuration of an ad-hoc created user.

What I have is: A user named 'master' with a MATE 1.12.1 desktop environment (running on CentOS7) perfectly configured: menus, background, icons, fonts, double monitor and other amenities.

What I need is: A fast method to copy its `GSettings/dconf` configuration and make it default / standard for every new / existent user.

Can anybody, please, detail step by step (also in pseudo code) how to do that and what to copy and where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set system-wide dconf settings by [storing them in a text file under `/etc/dconf/db/local.d`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf/SystemAdministrators#Keyfile_Directories) and running `dconf update`.

If you've set up things on a user's account, you can print out the settings in text form with the `dconf` command line utility. `dconf dump /` prints out all known settings but you should only retain the settings that you modified.

Comment: thanks, it worked. Everything in the key file was set as default for new and existing users. Only one thing tho: the applet menu (in "master" user is heavily customized - disabled menu voices via edit menu) does not retain the customization. maybe i have to copy the customized config during the login event. Have you a better idea eventually?

Comment: @Tetractys Sorry, I have no idea where this is configured.